# Copy one file content to another file and sort file avoiding duplicates

Tags: linux, shell, sorting, unix

I want to copy one file's content to another.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -le 2 ]; then
        if [ $# == 1 ]; then
                file2=$(/var/lab/ld2tlog/studlog)
                echo $file2
        else
                file2=$2
        fi
        if [ ! -e $1 ]; then
                cat $file2
                echo ( cat $file2 ) > $1
        else
                echo 'cat $file2' >> $1
        fi
else
        echo "Ivesta per daug argumentu!"
fi
```

And here's how I call my script

```
./myScript result file
```

and I only get this result:

```
nano result
file
```

So how do I copy one file's content to another.

**EDIT:**
I also need to avoid duplicate's

```
if [ ! -e $1 ]; then
                sort -u $file2
                cat $file2 > $1
fi
```

but I only get results printed to console,  not in my results file.

Comment: The `cat` command and I/O redirection are what you want; `echo` has no place in it.  Just `cat $file2 > $1` or `cat $file2 >> $1`, without quotes, parentheses, or `echo`.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if it is possible to sort my file avoiding dublicates? I have updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it all in one line:

```
sort -u "$1" > "${2:-/var/lab/ld2tlog/studlog}"
```

If you want to know the name of the output file, you can echo the output file name too:

```
outfile="${2:-/var/lab/ld2tlog/studlog}"
echo "$outfile"
sort -u "$1" > "$outfile"
```